# mysql select option_name where column match value and have any another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with sizes and colors

```
id      option_name
2969    M
2969    Black
2970    S
2970    Blue
2971    S
2971    Black
```

I need to select options which IDs are the same and also have option_name equal to Black. So I need get result:

```
2971    S
2969    M
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: There's nothing here to differentiate the "S" key from the "Black" key other than the length of the string. You need some kind of column to hint at why "S" and "M" are returned but "Black" and "Blue" are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sub query for detecting ids having option_name = black
and exclude option_name = black from main result
example

```
select 
`table`.`id`,
`table`.`option_name`
from 
`table`
where 
`table`.`option_name` <> "Black"
and 
`table`.`id` in(select `table`.`id` from `table` where `table`.`option_name` = "black")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines:

```
select t.id, t.option_name from mytable t
where t.option_name <> 'Black'
and t.id in (select m.id from mytable m where m.option_name = 'Black')
```